# Need help turning a for loop/if statement into a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I've got the following code:

```
var $elements = $("body").find("*");

for (var i = 0, len = $elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var $e = $elements.eq(i), 
        cssFloat = $e.css("float"), 
        cssDisplay = $e.css("display");

    if (cssDisplay !== "none" && 
       (cssFloat === "left" || cssFloat === "right")) { 

        $e.css("display", "inline"); 

    }

};
```

For performance reasons, I would like to replace the for loop and if statement with a jQuery selector that filters down all the elements to only the ones that need to apply the `display: inline;`.

I was thinking something along the lines of the following pseudo code:

```
$("body")

.find("*")
.not(selector for elements whose css display style is not "none")
.contains(selector for elements whose css float style is "left" or "right")    
.css("display", "inline");
```

For whatever reason, my brain is failing me. Is this possible?

Comment: There aren't any jQuery selectors that can query an element's style properties.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? I get the feeling that whatever it is, there's a better way.

Comment: For one thing, `float: left` (or `right`) forces `display: block`.

Comment: @thirtydot - I'm trying to fix the double padding / margin bug in IE6

Comment: @Scott: Why not do that in the stylesheet? It may be manual work, but it's much easier on you and the user.

Comment: @Scott: I see, that explains it. Well, I don't have enough information about exactly what's going on in your page to provide further advice, but there's *surely* a better way. Thanks to looking at *every element* on the page, your code is a performance catastrophe.

Comment: @BoltClock - Long story. JS is what I'm using for IE6 fixes at the moment.

Comment: @thirtydot - You're right. I mean unless there's a way to filter down elements based on a css style ... I don't know what else I can do JS wise other than what I'm doing.

Comment: The fact that you're targeting IE6 with this, plus the fact that IE6's DOM traversal/manipulation is horribly, horribly slow, means you're going to cripple your pages with this. This is pretty much a non-starter, I'm afraid!

Comment: @Scott: Why can't you just add `display: inline` alongside `float: left` in your CSS? It makes no difference in *any* browser, except that in IE6 it happens to fix a bug.

Comment: @thirtydot - I could. I'm just searching for the fastest JS way to do it.

Comment: @Scott: Using JavaScript for this makes no sense to me, but I accept that you want to use it. If you want the *fastest* code, then don't use jQuery, stick with raw JavaScript.

Comment: @thirtydot - I know ... I just didn't want to have to maintain the need for adding `display: inline` for every time `float: left;` is needed.  Plus, other team members can make changes as well, and I feel like I'd always be looking over my shoulder, so to speak, making sure no one forgets. But ... I did just break down and do one big find/replace all and commented out the JS. We'll see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `$.filter()` method to get what you want:

```
$(":visible").filter(function(index){
    return ( $.inArray( $(this).css('float'), ['left','right'] ) > -1 ); 
  }).css({display:'inline'});
```

This would result in the floated elements being turned into inline elements.

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/utape3/edit

While the jQuery documentation [states](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/#notes-0) there will be performance issues using `:visible`, it is more efficient than using `*` or `body *`.

**Performance Comparison**: http://jsperf.com/splat-vs-pseudo

I'm not sure of a faster method of doing this with JavaScript. You'll notice in the performance test that I used everything including a custom selector:

```
$.expr[':'].floated = function(obj) {
    return ($.inArray($(obj).css('float'), ['left', 'right']) > -1);
};

$(":floated").css({display:'inline'});
```

I was really only partly interested in the results of that method, not being entirely familiar with how the internals handle this type of selector.

**Raw JavaScript - Much Faster**

I've added to the performance testing the following:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  cssTxt = els[i].style.cssText;
  if ((cssTxt.indexOf('float: left') > -1) || (cssTxt.indexOf('float: right') > -1)) {
    els[i].style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

This test assumes:

```
<p style="float:left">Foo</p>
<p style="float:right">Bar</p>
```

This was thrown together, but ridiculously fast compared to the previous jQuery methods.

Comment: But it won't help incredibly much with performance -- it's just nicer functional code :)

Comment: `.children()` will only select direct children. He's after all descendants.

Comment: For what it's worth, he doesn't actually want to remove the `float` property. He's trying to do this with JavaScript for some (insane) reason: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

Comment: Yea, I was going to mention that setting float to none destroys my page.

Comment: @Scott Sorry for that oversight. I've updated my answer so as not to confuse the details.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, as it shows quite well that the RAW JS is the fastest method.  Thanks so much for the jsPerf tests.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a really bad idea.  But here's the jQuery to do roughly what you asked.  It's not going to help much because it's still going to have to look at pretty much everything on the page:

```
$(":visible").filter(function(){
    var cssFloat = $(this).css("float");

    return cssFloat === "left" || cssFloat === "right";
}).css("display", "inline");
```

Comment: This is what I had originally, but I found that [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com) is actually slower than my current method. Still +1 though.